# Customize the default search block

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

In the .theme file of my custom Drupal 8 theme, how do I customize the default search block so that I can add custom classes and also alter the input label to remove the word "search" but instead have a search icon from fontawesome?

Pretty much, I'd like the final output code to look like this:

```
<div class="infoBar-search">
  <form action="#!" class="searchForm">
    <input type="search" name="sitesearch" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="submit" class="searchForm-submit fa" value="&#xf002;">
  </form>
</div>
```

Would the .theme approach be the best way to go about this? I tried altering a few template files but noticed this would affect the other forms on the site as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this can be done more elegantly , but I was able to do this with a #icon_variable from the form[] to change the input suggestion. I just added side that I want the icon on the button and an extra option to ...-icon-class.html.twig etc.

1) Add a suggestion to the input

```
function MODULE_theme_suggestions_input_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {

   if (isset($variables['element']['#icon']) || isset($variables['element']['#icon-left']) || isset($variables['element']['#icon-right'])) {
         $suggestions[] = 'input__submit_icon';
         if (isset($variables['element']['#icon'])) {
           $suggestions[] = 'input__submit_icon_' . $variables['element']['#icon'];
         }
      }
   }
```

Then I can add/alter this on the form:

```
   $form['actions']['submit']['#icon-left'] = 'icon-class';
```

With a template like `input__submit_icon.html.twig` :

```
<button {{ attributes }} >
    {% if element['#icon-left'] %}
        <i class="{{ element['#icon-left'] }}"></i>
    {% endif %}
    {{ attributes.value }}
    {% if element['#icon-right'] %}
        <i class="{{ element['#icon-right'] }}"></i>
    {% endif %}
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First use the search block of drupal 8 and then override the search form with hook_form_alter function. and then finally render that block in the template file.

First override this twig file in your custom theme template.
        block--search-form-block.html.twig

 `div class="infoBar-search">
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if label %}
    {{ label }}
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  {% block content %}
    {{ content }}
  {% endblock %}
 /div>`

Correct the div tag.
Then use hook_form_alter in .theme file to alter what ever u want to alter.

`function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'searchForm';
    $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search...');
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = '"searchForm-submit fa';
  }`

Comment: hmm, I've tried this but something must not be working correctly as nothing changes. I've changed both the twig file and .theme file and nothing. Any suggestions as to why? _(Yes, I've cleared the cache)_

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Recheck your code and put the code which i commented coz it works as i have tried.

Comment: I was placing exact function name `hook_form_alter`, then identified that i should use theme name there something like `my_theme_form_alter`. Hope this may help someone who stuck like me.